# Pseudo R-squared for glm.cluster object

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, coefficient-of-determination

I have estimated several glms with cluster robust standard errors using the function `glm.cluster()` from the `miceadds` package in R.

Unfortunately, the function does not automatically calculate a pseudo R-squared.
Moreover, I am unable to find a package for calculating a pseudo R-squared that is compatible with `glm.cluster`. So far, I have tried `rcompanion`'s `nagelkerke()`, `fmsb`’s `NagelkerkeR2()` and even `psfmi`'s `rsq_nagel()`.

Did anyone else face this problem before and do you know how to resolve it without writing one's own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glm.cluster` returns a two-element list, the first element of which (called `$glm_res`) is the actual `glm` fit.  I used `performance::r2_nagelkerke()` because that was what I had handy, but any Nagelkerke R2 function will probably work if you apply it to the `$glm_res` component.

Set up example:

```r
data(data.ma01, package = "miceadds")
dat <- data.ma01
dat$highmath <- 1 * ( dat$math > 600 )   # create dummy variable
mod2 <- miceadds::glm.cluster( data=dat, formula=highmath ~ hisei + female,
                     cluster="idschool", family="binomial")
```

```r
library(performance)
r2_nagelkerke(mod2$glm_res)
## Nagelkerke's R2 
## 0.05126081
```